# How to send notification messages to devices within a geolocation area?

Tags: android, notifications, geolocation

I'm developing an application for android mobile devices.

In a given moment application server must query all devices within an geolocation area and send notification messages to all found devices in that area.

In a specified interval all devices will update their positions by making a request to a service which will store that positioning data. However, besides lat/long values what more data must be stored in order to identify the devices and make possible to query based on their stored position and send the notifications ?

Comment: you can use timezones just like parse. But you need to maintain list of time zones

Comment: That's ok but I mean a narrower area, such as 3 miles away from a given coordinate.

Comment: i have no idea. I am guessing may be you will have to get user location. But that can vary from user to user.

Comment: I think I should be more clear on this question. What I need is to notify some devices that are inside a specific location delimited by distance from a coordinate.